# How to rescale a element in a scaled container

Tags: actionscript-3

Im trying to scale the pattern element before i use the same element in this
`_mesh.graphics.beginBitmapFill(_box, matrix, true, true);`, but it doesnt consider it and it doesnt scale the pattern element> only the background.
this is the pattern element used for filling the background with the name of "**Box**"

[image: the pattern element]

this is the code in the class that i have so far for the creating of the effect that i want

```
                private var _mesh:Shape = new Shape();
                private var _box:BitmapData = new Box();

                public function CreateRow_Col() {
                          addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, zzz);
                }


                private function zzz(e:Event):void {
                          removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, zzz);
                          var stageW:Number = stage.stageWidth
                          var stageH:Number = stage.stageHeight
                          var elementW = _box.width
                          var elementH = _box.height
                          var numberElements_W = Math.ceil(stageW / elementW)
                          var numberElements_H = Math.ceil(stageH / elementH)
                          var ScaleX:Number = 1
                          var ScaleY:Number = 51
                          var background_W = numberElements_W * elementW * ScaleX
                          var background_H = numberElements_H * elementH * ScaleY
                          //trace(background_W + " = "+ numberElements_W + " * " + elementW)
                          var  matrix:Matrix = new Matrix()
                          matrix.scale(ScaleX,ScaleY);
                          _mesh.graphics.beginBitmapFill(_box, matrix, true, true);
                          _mesh.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, background_W, background_H);
                          _mesh.graphics.endFill();
                          _mesh.x = _mesh.y = 0;
                          _mesh.scaleX = stageW / background_W;
                          _mesh.scaleY = stageH / background_H;
                          trace(stageH / background_H)
                          addChild(_mesh);
                }


      }
```

}

What i mean > when i comment the `/*_mesh.scaleX = stageW / background_W;
                              _mesh.scaleY = stageH / background_H;*/`
i have 2 rows like it must do ,cause ill have different scaleX and Y that will change depending on some events(the element will get bigger or smaller)
[image]

but when i uncomment the _mesh.ScaleX and Y i dont get the 2 rows fit in the entire scree like i want , I get 5 rows (they are purfectly sized to fit the stage.stageWidth or Height - what i want but not allways five).And even worse when i change the ScaleY or X of the pattern element to any number like .5 or 51 or 501 it just doesnt care >> i always get 5 rows.

[image]

can this be fixed ?

the stage has 550x400 dimensions 
and the element has 63x83 dimensions

EDIT:
well it needs to look when `var ScaleY:Number = 3` like this[image]

when `var ScaleY:Number = 2` like this

[image]

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you are trying to do. Can you try to clarify the question, or at least post an image of how it should look when it's done right.

Comment: i edited my post and included how they would need to look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var stageW : Number = stage.stageWidth;
var stageH : Number = stage.stageHeight;

var container : Sprite = new Sprite();

var tileN : Number = 3;
var tileM : Number = 7;

var tileW : Number = stageW / tileM;
var tileH : Number = stageH / tileN;
for (var i:int = 0; i < tileN; i++) 
{
    for (var j:int = 0; j < tileM; j++) 
    {
        var tile : Sprite = new Sprite();
        tile.graphics.lineStyle( 1, 0xFF0000 );
        tile.graphics.beginFill( 0x0000FF, 1 );
        tile.graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, tileW, tileH );
        tile.graphics.endFill();
        tile.x = j * tileW;
        tile.y = i * tileH;

        container.addChild( tile );
    }               
}
container.width = stageW;
container.height = stageH;

addChild( container );
```

Comment: Well this is what i am trying. so lets say the screen/fla dimension  goes 1000x500 from it default value of 500x400.I make everything rescale(including the Box width and height),that is why i use the MATRIX.So now the box is bigger yet i then need to fit that new rows and column exactly in the stage (in this scenario 2) and that is why im reScaling the _mesh> so it fits the screen. but as seen above it doesnt consider the MATRIX scaling. im using   `var ScaleY:Number = 51` here cause im simulating the resizing of the project values.
PS:it wasnt me >i didnt downvote it, dont have the reputation

Comment: Stop saying code, use description on what you want. So you have say 4/3 rows and when you resize the stage you want, like 7/5 and the background squares having the same size in either state?

Comment: i need all the rows to be visible no matter how many they are(they must not be cropped) and when i rescale the element they need to get less for this dimension and again to not be cropped (like in the EDIT i just made)

Comment: Yea yea this does work but ,well i need it to do that with a bitmap image(pattern element) and :S im using the `graphics.beginBitmapFill` cause i need as less elements as possible on the stage.and i cant say how many rows and col it must have > it will depend on the new stage dimensions

Comment: so use beginBitmapFill instead of line and solid fill and for tileN and tileM divide the stageW and stageH by an arbitrary number like 100 then change it to tweak your stuf.

Comment: ok it does work that way.but that way i create as much elements on the stage as blocks that i have(or im doint it wrong and thats why i get with 4cols and 5 rows 20 elm, not like 1 object that repeats it self). yet with your help i think i know now what to do> i Just have to rescale the object (the pattern element ) before i use it and then save it as a different object (like rescaled_box) and use that instance for the `graphics.beginBitmapFill` and dont use Matrix as your 1st told me .Now i just have to recollect / find how to do that.Thanks allot for your time and help :)

Comment: you are welcome. you can just remove the container then call the method in my example (all of it) and it will recalculate everything. good luck